Using \edef inside an enumerate environment not updating the existing value
I'm trying to use the approach described in this answer to store some text for later. My code is as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\edef\answers{}
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\edef\answers{\answers{}#1 }}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Question. 
    \answer{answer}
    \item Question. 
    \answer{another answer}
\end{enumerate}

\answers

\end{document}

However, when I use this, the specified answers are not appended to the content of \answers.  They are correctly added, however, if I use the \answer command outside of the enumerate environment. How can I make this work inside of the environment?

the enumerate environment is a group so the value of \answers is restored at the end, but it is never safe to use user supplied latex markup in an \edef many commands will give low level TeX errors if used in `\edef.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

[This is exactly the sort of answer I ought not write ...]
As David commented, enumerate forms a group and \edef defines \answers locally, so that definition only persists until the end of the group. After \end{enumerate} the definition vanishes.
The global equivalent of \edef is \xdef. So you could substitute \xdef for \edef:
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\answers{}% make sure we aren't overwriting an existing definition
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\xdef\answers{\answers{}#1 }}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Question.
    \answer{answer}
  \item Question.
    \answer{another answer}
\end{enumerate}

\answers

\end{document}

However, as also indicated in David's comment, this is extremely fragile. For example, if we change
    \answer{another answer}

to, say,
    \answer{another answer $\sqrt{-1}$}

the thing will implode. Perhaps that's OK if you you're not using any maths, but you presumably use fonts and
    \answer{another answer \textbf{-1}}

will break things just as badly.
What you want is to capture one expansion of the old \answers in the definition of the new one. The problem is that \edef and \xdef don't know when to stop, expanding everything expandable.
Pick your poison:

stick with low-level TeX stuff and control expansion with e.g. \expandafter;
use one of the newer 2e methods, such as \ExpandArgs to control expansion;
use one of the newer expl3 programming methods;
something else1.

Method 1
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\answers{}
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\answers\expandafter{\answers #1 }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Question.
    \answer{answer $\sqrt{-1}$}
  \item Question.
    \answer{another answer \textbf{-1}}
\end{enumerate}

\answers

\end{document}

Method 2
The new 2e framework is generally very nice, but it doesn't work very well in this particular case, so, personally, I'd steer clear of this method. In fact, I'm not even sure which method it is. It uses \ExpandArgs from the new 2e stuff, \newcommand and \renewcommand from the old 2e stuff and \global\let from the underlying TeX stuff. This is largely because the new way of creating macros has all costs and no benefits in this particular instance, so it only really makes sense2 to take \ExpandArgs from that framework.
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\answers{}
\NewDocumentCommand\answer{+m}{%
  \ExpandArgs {No}\renewcommand\answers{\answers\ #1}%
  \global\let\answers\answers
}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Question.
    \answer{answer $\sqrt{-1}$}
  \item Question.
    \answer{another answer \textbf{-1}}
\end{enumerate}

\answers

\end{document}

Method 3
This method uses a weird-looking alien syntax, but it offers various advantages:

we can use a ready-made thingy to hold the answers e.g. a sequence, a comma-separated list, a token list ...;
separating the input and output comes for free, so you can typeset your answers using different formats and separators;
somebody else dealt with all the expansion mess, so we don't have to.

\answer{} works just as before syntax-wise, so no changes there. Under-the-hood is does far less than before. All it does is append its argument to a global comma-separated list.
\answers[] works just as before by default, so no changes required. However, it now takes an optional argument in case you'd like to separate the answers with something other than a space. The code below illustrates three flavours: original (space), semicolon and enumerated list.

\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_jules_answers_clist
\NewDocumentCommand \answer { +m }
{
  \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_jules_answers_clist { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \answers { O { ~ } }
{
  \clist_use:Nn \g_jules_answers_clist { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Question.
    \answer{answer $\sqrt{-1}$}
  \item Question.
    \answer{another answer \textbf{-1}}
\end{enumerate}

\answers

\answers[; ]

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \answers[\item]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

1Various third-party (and sometimes second-party) packages have been written to provide assistance with this kind of machinery. Since we have methods in the LaTeX format now, there isn't much reason to use those for new code, so I ignore them here.
2That is, I could only make sense of this. Your kilometres, nanometres and/or light years may vary.

The usage of \tempa in Mathod 1 is redundant. The usage of empty group {} is redundant too. The key command can look like \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\answers\expandafter{\answers#1 }.

@wipet thanks ...

I did say it is exactly the sort of answer I ought not write ....

Using \edef is very risky (almost like slippery roads ).
The LaTeX kernel provides from day one \g@addto@macro for such jobs:
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\answers{}
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro{\answers}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Question.
    \answer{answer}
    \item Question.
    \answer{another answer}
\end{enumerate}

\answers

\end{document}


However this is clearly unsatisfactory, because you surely want to format answers in some way, for instance attaching the question number.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\answer}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Ne \g_jules_answers_seq
   {
    \__jules_answer:nn {\arabic{enumi}} { \exp_not:n {#1} }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\answers}{}
 {
  \par
  \seq_use:Nn \g_jules_answers_seq { \par }
  \par
 }

\seq_new:N \g_jules_answers_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jules_answer:nn
 {
  \par\noindent(#1)~#2\par
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Question. 
    \answer{answer}
    \item Question. 
    \answer{another answer}
\end{enumerate}

\answers

\end{document}



Hi@egreg The personal link in your profile page is broken. Could you fix it?
